# Connection refused when calling docker engine api from react app in browser

Tags: reactjs, docker, http

I have a `react app` from which I want to call the docker engine api to start a container when a user clicks a button. There are a series of commands from a bash script I wrote that I am trying to replicate in the browser. The first command is to create a series of volumes.

```
docker volume create volume-test
```

When I first try to create the volume when sending the http request from the app using `axios` to the docker engine, I get a `connection refused` error. When run the same command, using `curl` from my command line, the volume is created.

Can someone please explain why and how to resolve this?

Working curl command to create volume

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Name": "volume-test"}' -X POST http://localhost/v1.41/volumes/create
```

Axios api call from react app that fails:

```
async generateDockerVolumes() {
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/v1.41/volumes/create",
        socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock",
        data: {
          Name: "volume-test",
        },
      });
      console.log("Response from axios ", res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error generating docker volumes ", err);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't do this.  Remember that, if you can start a container, you can pretty trivially root the whole host.  Browsers are generally configured to not allow access to the host filesystem (so you can't access the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket).  Consider what it would mean if this was possible, and an arbitrary Web-hosted ad could launch a container like this (or any other process) without the specific "user clicks a button" requirement.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think this was possible, but like with everything, there could have been someone who had managed it. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't suppose this would be any different for a Progressive Web App running in offline mode?